# SocketIO - connection not recognized (?) after a couple of messages exchanged

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, python-socketio

I'm running a JS socketio client and a Python socketio server. The workflow is roughly `client emitting event1 to server` -> `server reacting to event1, running analysis and emitting event2 to client` -> `client receives event2 and emits event1 again but with different args` -> `etc until loop is complete`

The problem is that this workflow only works for two iterations, for some reasons after that the server logs show:

```
received event "event1" from None [/]
None is not connected to namespace /
received event "event1" from None [/]
None is not connected to namespace /
received event "event1" from None [/]
None is not connected to namespace /
received event "event1" from None [/]
```

I have no idea whatsoever what might be the reason. I've searched through the docs but can't seem to find any parameters that might be responsible for that.

Client:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const socket = io("http://localhost:5550/",
{
  timeout: 200000000000
});

socket.emit('event1', args)
socket.on('event2', (msg) => {
        ...
        });
```

Server:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
sio = socketio.Server(logger=True, cors_allowed_origins='*')
app.wsgi_app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5550)), app)
```

I appreciate any help/tips you can provide, thanks!

Comment: Check for connection errors and other listeners to determine what's going on.

Comment: The problem is that server logs don't show any connection errors, nor does the client. Is there any other way to debug it properly?